# Can't enable Jsonp in Geoserver 2.7.0 and then publishing my WFS request in Leaflet

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wfs, json

I'm working on localhost:8080 and want to get WFS data in a Leaflet map.
So, I've read in some posts here that I first I have to enable Jsonp in my web.xml file in Geoserver.
So I put

```
<context-param>
<param-name>ENABLE_JSONP</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But I can't see that Jsonp is allowed with a getCapabilities :

```
<ows:Parameter name="outputFormat">
<ows:AllowedValues>
<ows:Value>text/xml; subtype=gml/3.2</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>GML2</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>KML</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>SHAPE-ZIP</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>application/gml+xml; version=3.2</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>application/json</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>application/vnd.google-earth.kml xml</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>application/x-gpkg</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>csv</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>geopackage</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>geopkg</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>gml3</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>gml32</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>gpkg</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>json</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>text/xml; subtype=gml/2.1.2</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1</ows:Value>
</ows:AllowedValues>
```

Then, I tried to load my WFS data into a GeoJson layer in leaflet with this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Test WFS</title>        

<link 
    rel="stylesheet" 
    href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css"
/>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>    
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
var center = new L.LatLng(46.707, 4.678);
var map = new L.Map('map', { center: center, zoom: 14, minZoom:11});    

var owsrootUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Vin/ows';

var defaultParameters = {
    service : 'WFS',
    version : '2.0.0',
    request : 'GetFeature',
    typeName : 'Vin:vinChalon',
    maxFeatures : 50,
    outputFormat: 'json'
};

var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters);

var URL = owsrootUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters);

var ajax = $.ajax({
    url : URL,
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback : 'getJson',
    success : WFSLayer
}); 

function WFSLayer(data) {
L.geoJson(data, {
style: function (feature) {
    return {color: 'black',
        fillColor: '#ff0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.10};
    }
}).addTo(map);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And firefox's console return

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement    ows:1:7
```

Is someone knows why it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you restartet Tomcat / Geoserver after editing the web.xml?

Your capabilities should show this entry:

```
<ows:Value>text/javascript</ows:Value>
```

Your javascript-code seems ok. --> slightly adapted with an other Geoserver/Layer here:
http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/u1oskkxy/

Comment: Many thanks for your reply Thomas B. Yes, now jsonp is allowed.

Comment: But if I enclose my geoJson in my ajax function, it works, if not, like in your code, it doesn't works ...